# Protected void error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, repository

I am a bit new to c# and I have some problems with my code.

I get the error **Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct over Page Load and Button2_Click Voids**.

My code seems fine and it was working fine early.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using c365_EntityFramework;
using c365_EntityFramework.Repository;
using ICSWebCommon;
using ICSWebControls;
using Obout.Grid;
using ICSWebPortal.AppCode;

namespace ICSWebPortal.Portal.Controls.Users
{
    public partial class CreateUser : ICSBaseUserControl
    {
        UserRepository userDao = new UserRepository();
        User user = new User();
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-09-14 00:00:00.000");
    }
}


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
}
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
            {
                user.Title = txtTitle.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
            {
                user.Forename = txtFirstName.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSurname.Text))
            {
                user.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text))
            {
                user.Username = txtUsername.Text;
            }
            // call save function at end of statements 
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress.Text))
            {
                user.Address1 = txtAddress.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress2.Text))
            {
                user.Address2 = txtAddress.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPostcode.Text))
            {
                user.PostCode = txtPostcode.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCode.Text))
            {
                user.CountryCode = txtCode.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text))
            {
                user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            }
            //if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDate.Text))
            //{
            //    DateTime _entrydate;
            //    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out _entrydate))
            //    {
            //        user.EntryDate = _entrydate;
            //    }
            //}
            user.CompanyID = AppSession.Company.ID;
            user.Status = 1;
            user.PasswordHash = "test";
            user.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.Deleted = false;
            bool result = userDao.SaveNewUser(user);
            if (result)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/User/List/UserList.aspx"); //~ for root directory , if there is any page use that or use the exact url here.
            }
}
```

**Current Code**

```
   using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using c365_EntityFramework;
using c365_EntityFramework.Repository;
using ICSWebCommon;
using ICSWebControls;
using Obout.Grid;
using ICSWebPortal.AppCode;

namespace ICSWebPortal.Portal.Controls.Users
{
    public partial class CreateUser : ICSBaseUserControl
    {
        UserRepository userDao = new UserRepository();
        User user = new User();
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-09-14 00:00:00.000");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
            {
                user.Title = txtTitle.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
            {
                user.Forename = txtFirstName.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSurname.Text))
            {
                user.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text))
            {
                user.Username = txtUsername.Text;
            }
            // call save function at end of statements 
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress.Text))
            {
                user.Address1 = txtAddress.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress2.Text))
            {
                user.Address2 = txtAddress.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPostcode.Text))
            {
                user.PostCode = txtPostcode.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCode.Text))
            {
                user.CountryCode = txtCode.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text))
            {
                user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            }
            //if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDate.Text))
            //{
            //    DateTime _entrydate;
            //    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out _entrydate))
            //    {
            //        user.EntryDate = _entrydate;
            //    }
            //}
            user.CompanyID = AppSession.Company.ID;
            user.Status = 1;
            user.PasswordHash = "test";
            user.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.Deleted = false;
            bool result = userDao.SaveNewUser(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: methods should be inside class

Answer (score 2):

You have ended your class and namespace:

```
namespace ICSWebPortal.Portal.Controls.Users
{
    public partial class CreateUser : ICSBaseUserControl
    {
        UserRepository userDao = new UserRepository();
        User user = new User();
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-09-14 00:00:00.000");


    } // these should be after your methods
}     //
```

Comment: so you removed those 2x `}` I pointed out above and added them all the way down at the bottom?

Comment: Yes could you post the code you think would work so I can test.

Comment: What is the error? Is it still the same? In visual studio or when you try to build it?

Comment: Because I now get an error for user saying method is defined more than once

Comment: When debugging or building

Comment: OK add your current code to your question, underneath what you have already posted

Comment: What do you mean *get an error for user saying method is defined more than once* - I thought the error was on the Button2_Click method?

Comment: It was but when I take away the 2 }} and add them to the bottom I get this error aswell

Comment: What lines are the errors on? Please post them...from what I can see there should be no problem with that code

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using c365_EntityFramework;
using c365_EntityFramework.Repository;
using ICSWebCommon;
using ICSWebControls;
using Obout.Grid;
using ICSWebPortal.AppCode;

namespace ICSWebPortal.Portal.Controls.Users
{
    public partial class CreateUser : ICSBaseUserControl
    {
        UserRepository userDao = new UserRepository();
        User user = new User();
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-09-14 00:00:00.000");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
            {
                user.Title = txtTitle.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
            {
                user.Forename = txtFirstName.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSurname.Text))
            {
                user.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text))
            {
                user.Username = txtUsername.Text;
            }
            // call save function at end of statements 
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress.Text))
            {
                user.Address1 = txtAddress.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress2.Text))
            {
                user.Address2 = txtAddress.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPostcode.Text))
            {
                user.PostCode = txtPostcode.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCode.Text))
            {
                user.CountryCode = txtCode.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text))
            {
                user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            }

            user.CompanyID = AppSession.Company.ID;
            user.Status = 1;
            user.PasswordHash = "test";
            user.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.Deleted = false;
            bool result = userDao.SaveNewUser(user);
            if (result)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/User/List/UserList.aspx"); //~ for root directory , if there is any page use that or use the exact url here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```